# why is my php/mysql search string only matching the LAST keyword?

Tags: php, mysql, search, foreach

I have a search function that is supposed to take all the keywords in an array from $keywords_search and then create the correct mySQL statement to get the results. The problem is, when I search for multiple keywords, it seems to find only results that match the LAST keyword in the array. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
$sr='';
foreach(explode(" ",$keywords_search) as $value){

    $sr="a.name LIKE '%".$value."%' AND";

}
$query[] = substr($sr,0,-4);
```

It's supposed to search for

```
a.name LIKE '%keyword1%' AND
a.name LIKE '%keyword2%' AND
a.name LIKE '%keyword3%'
```

The var_dump(); for $query shows only the output for the last keyword, while the var_dump(); for the $keywords_search shows all keywords.

Comment: Be careful that you don't open yourself up to some nasty SQL injection!  Also, consider adding all of your SQL for the `LIKE` statement (what's in `$sr`) to an array, and then exploding them with `explode(' AND ', $array_of_sr)` so that you don't have to do the ugly `substr()` at the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make it like this

```
$sr='';
foreach(explode(" ",$keywords_search) as $value){

    $sr .= " a.name LIKE '%".$value."%' AND";

}
$query[] = substr($sr,0,-4);
```

you forgot to put a `.` for appending.

Comment: Wow, how stupid of me! :D I was searching for big issues when it was such a little one. Thank you!